# Get DOM (selector) element when calling jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I access the actual element a plugin is called on from within the plugin call itself? `$(this)` seems to refer to the plugin context not the actual element.

For example I am calling the pluginName plugin on an input field and I want a callback to change that input's value. This is a generic example. Element can be a tag, a class, an id etc.

```
$('element').pluginName({
    option: true,
    option: false,
    onSelect: function(item){
        $(this).val('something');
        //console.log($(this));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of `this` within the `onSelect` event will be determined by how the library is structured, and how the internal call is made to that event handler. The ideal solution would be to set the scope of the `onSelect` handler to be the element itself, or at least provide it to the handler as an argument.

If that's not possible and you want to retain the reference to the `#input` element you can select it again, as there should only be a single instance of an element with that `id`:

```
onSelect: function(item){
  $('#input').val('something');
}
```

If you were using a class to select multiple elements then you would need to loop through them:

```
$('.input').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.pluginName({
    option: true,
    option: false,
    onSelect: function(item) { 
      $el.val('something');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: True, I have rephrased the question as the solution was mean to be a generic one, not strictly related to a scenario using and ID as selector. How would I set the scope of the `onSelect` handler to be the element itself?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way if your plugin does not allow. One thing you can do is

```
var $el = $('#input');

$el.pluginName({
    option: true,
    option: false,
    onSelect: function(item){
        $el.val('something');
    }
});
```

Comment: Essentially the same answer as the selected one but that one was the first given :)